# xml flv playlist with randomization AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flv, playlist

I'm trying to create a function that calls random videos from an XML playlist in AS3 and have no idea where to start. I've tried multiple methods and am breaking my brain. Please halp!

although i have had some luck pulling in videos, the randomization doesn't work and I also need to grab the titles from the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<playlist>
        <video url="video/flvs/04-02-02-09-01.flv" title="angry" />    
        <video url="video/flvs/14-02-01-08-01.flv" title="happy"  />    
        <video url="video/flvs/04-02-01-04-01.flv" title="sad"  />
        <video url="video/flvs/06-02-02-03-01.flv" title="frustrated"  />
        <video url="video/flvs/21-02-02-08-01.flv" title="no emotion"  />
</playlist>
```

AS3:

```
function Init():void{
    _urlRequest = new URLRequest("playlist.xml");
    _xmlLoader = new URLLoader();
    _xmlLoader = new URLLoader(_urlRequest);
    _xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, XMLLoaded, false, 0, true);
}

function XMLLoaded($e:Event):void {
    _xml = new XML($e.target.data);
    var randomVideo:XML = _xml.video[Math.floor(_xml.video.length() * Math.random())];
    PlayVideo();
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some relevant code and we can help you workout the solution. Also, `Math.Random()` is your friend.

Comment: not sure where to place the snppet @bwroga sent. i guessed. didnt work.

`function Init():void{

        _urlRequest = new URLRequest("playlist.xml");
 
 _xmlLoader = new URLLoader();
 _xmlLoader = new URLLoader(_urlRequest);
 _xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, XMLLoaded, false, 0, true);
 
}

function XMLLoaded($e:Event):void
{
 _xml = new XML($e.target.data);
 var randomVideo:XML = _xml.video[Math.floor(_xml.video.length() * Math.random())];
 PlayVideo();
}
`

Comment: What is the code for `PlayVideo()`? This should be working to get a random entry. Your problem now must be on the `PlayVideo()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a random playlist node like this (assuming your XML is referenced by a variable called "xml"):

```
var randomVideo:XML = xml.video[Math.floor(xml.video.length() * Math.random())];
```

You can access the attributes like this:

```
var randomURL:String = randomVideo.@url;
var randomTitle:String = randomVideo.@title;
```

Comment: Ended up using this to find and sort the videos by description.<br/>
`function playRandomVideo () {
    randomVideo = Math.floor(Math.random() * emotionArray[randomEmotion].length);
    randomDescription = Math.floor(Math.random() * emotionArray.length);
currentVideo = emotionArray[randomDescription][randomVideo][0];
currentDescription = emotionArray[randomDescription][randomVideo][1];
addGameVideo();
}`
<br/> thanks for your help guys